# PHP exec - check if enabled or disabled

Tags: php, linux, unix, exec

Is there a way to check in a php script if `exec()` is enabled or disabled on a server?

Comment: What do you mean by *"enabled or disabled"* ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect - it will only detect whether the function is available. Most servers will disable it via INI, which means the function will still be present but throw a warning when run and not do anything.

See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938120/check-if-exec-is-disabled

Comment: @pospi That's nonsense; `function_exists()` also checks whether a function is disabled - [proof](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#1349)

Comment: @Jack is that a statement you'd be comfortable making across all possible combinations of PHP versions and server APIs? (;

Comment: @pospi You mean for versions of PHP that aren't EOL? Sure.

Comment: @Jack hah, that's fair. But we don't all have the luxury of maintaining sites developed this side of 2003! I would say it's a gotcha to be aware of if you're working on pre-5.3 code but not something to worry about otherwise.

Comment: @pospi's comment is correct .  There are cases where the PHP check in function_exists does not properly verify that the function is not present in the disabled list, and additional checking is required.

Answer (score 68):

This will check if the function actually works (permissions, rights, etc):

```
if(@exec('echo EXEC') == 'EXEC'){
    echo 'exec works';
}
```

Comment: This is actually a better answer :-)

Comment: As @Umbrella told, definitely it will throw warnings

Comment: @Umbrella @Thamaraiselvam You should use `@exec`, the `@` will suppress warning level errors

Answer (score 10):

**ini_get('disable_functions')**

What you actually want to do is use `ini_get('disable_functions')` to find out if it is available to you:

```
<?php
function exec_enabled() {
    $disabled = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
    return !in_array('exec', $disabled);
}
?>
```

Answered on stackoverflow here: [Check if "exec" is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938120/check-if-exec-is-disabled), Which actually seems to come from the PHP Man page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#97187

**Path**

If the above returns true (you can use exec()), but PHP can still not trigger the script there is a good chance that you have a path issue for that script, test this by doing:

```
print exec('which bash');
```

and then try

```
print exec('which ogr2ogr');
```

Answer (score 6):

This will check that exec is available and enabled BEFORE trying to run it.  If you run exec() and the function does not exist or is disabled a warning will be generated.  Depending on the server settings that may render to the browser and will almost-always write a line to a log file = performance hit.

```
// Exec function exists.
// Exec is not disabled.
// Safe Mode is not on.
$exec_enabled =
   function_exists('exec') &&
   !in_array('exec', array_map('trim', explode(', ', ini_get('disable_functions')))) &&
   strtolower(ini_get('safe_mode')) != 1
;


if($exec_enabled) { exec('blah'); }
```

Comment: please note - ini_get('safe_mode') can return not only "off", but also "" (empty string)

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit tricky to find `exec` function available until unless checking all possibilities

1.`function_exist('exec')`

2.Scanning through `ini_get('disabled_functions)`

3.Checking `safe_mode` enabled

```
function is_shell_exec_available() {
    if (in_array(strtolower(ini_get('safe_mode')), array('on', '1'), true) || (!function_exists('exec'))) {
        return false;
    }
    $disabled_functions = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
    $exec_enabled = !in_array('exec', $disabled_functions);
    return ($exec_enabled) ? true : false;
}
```

This function never throws warnings unless `ini_get` function not disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are running this on a linux server.

You could test the exec function by running the following php script:

```
exec("whoami", $ret);

echo $ret[0];
```

This will return the command whoami.

If it errors out, it is because the exec function could not run.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
if(strpos(ini_get('disable_functions'),'ini_set')===false) 
    @ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some ugly code I made to detect if a function is enabled or not.

```
function is_enabled($f)
{
    if($f=='ini_get')return@ini_get('a')===false;
    return(($l=@ini_get('disable_functions'))===null||!is_callable($f)||!function_exists($f)||!in_array($f,array_map('trim',explode(',',$l)));
}

//Usage example:
print_r(is_enabled('str_split'));//true or null if ini_get() is disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

(Based on other responses)
To check if **exec** exists and services are running:

```
function isRunning($serviceName)
{
    return exec('pgrep '.$serviceName);
}

if (@exec('echo EXEC') == 'EXEC') {
    $services = [
        'mysql',
        'nginx',
        'redis',
        'supervisord',
    ];

    foreach ($services as $service) {
        if (isRunning($service)) {
            echo $service.' service is running.<br>';
        } else {
            echo $service.' service is down.<br>';
        }
    }
}

// mysql service is running.
// nginx service is running.
// redis service is running.
// supervisord service is down.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
if (in_array('exec', preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', ini_get('disable_functions')) {
  echo "exec is disabled";
}
```