# Check if "exec" is disabled

Tags: php, exec

Is there any function in PHP that I can use to detect whether or not the `exec` function is available?

Comment: `echo (int)function_exists('exec');`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
<?php
function exec_enabled() {
  $disabled = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
  return !in_array('exec', $disabled);
}
?>
```

EDIT: Fixed the explode as per Ziagl's comment.

Comment: This returns `true` if `exec` is enabled.

Comment: that's why the function is called exec_enabled, it's just not exactly what he asked for.

Comment: this might work or it might not - unfortunately, in my case, I found that `ini_get()` was in the list of disabled functions along with `exec` and other file-system functions; a likely scenario, given that hosting providers might be concerned about exposing information in the INI file.

Comment: works for me, but only with explode(',' ... instead of explode(', ' ...there are no blanks in ini_get string

Comment: I had to post process the return of explode with trim to strip off blanks.

Answer (score 14):

The following function is more robust.  It deals with the `disabled_functions` value having 0 or more spaces between function names, checks the suhosin patch's blacklist setting, covers `safe_mode`, and stores the answer for future reference.

```
function is_exec_available() {
    static $available;

    if (!isset($available)) {
        $available = true;
        if (ini_get('safe_mode')) {
            $available = false;
        } else {
            $d = ini_get('disable_functions');
            $s = ini_get('suhosin.executor.func.blacklist');
            if ("$d$s") {
                $array = preg_split('/,\s*/', "$d,$s");
                if (in_array('exec', $array)) {
                    $available = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $available;
}
```

Comment: For the record, the edit adding the suhosin blacklist check was by me.  After submitting it, I realized my authentication session was somehow out of whack.  Alas.

Answer (score 2):

You can search the ini setting `disable_functions` for the `exec()` function.

```
if( false !== strpos(ini_get("disable_functions"), "exec") ) {
 // exec() is disabled
```

Just for completeness, note that PHP [Safe Mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php) puts some restrictions on the function too.

Comment: Way too slow as I see :)

Comment: This will return the wrong answer if a function like `shell_exec` has been placed in `disable_functions` but `exec` has not. Best to use explode or regex to make sure it matches a complete function name.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to check whether safe_mode is active as exec is unavailable if safe_mode is on

```
function is_exec_available() {

    // Are we in Safe Mode
    if ( $safe_mode = ini_get( 'safe_mode' ) && strtolower( $safe_mode ) != 'off' )
        return false;

    // Is shell_exec disabled?
    if ( in_array( 'exec', array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', ini_get( 'disable_functions' ) ) ) ) )
        return false;

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-line compilation of safe mode, function exists, and disabled exec using some of the techniques found on various SO posts.

This will check that exec is available and enabled BEFORE trying to run it.  If you run exec() and the function does not exist or is disabled a warning will be generated.  Depending on the server settings that may render to the browser and will almost-always write a line to a log file = performance hit.

```
// Exec function exists.
// Exec is not disabled.
// Safe Mode is not on.
$exec_enabled =
     function_exists('exec')                                            &&
     !in_array('exec', array_map('trim',explode(', ', ini_get('disable_functions'))))     &&
              !(strtolower( ini_get( 'safe_mode' ) ) != 'off')
     ;


if ($exec_enabled) { exec('blah'); }
```