# Executing a java .jar file with php

Tags: php, exec

I have made a .jar file that joins two wave files together.I call it with the command prompt like so.

java -jar WaveAppender.jar 1.wav 2.wav out.wav

I am trying to use php now to execute this .jar file,but the code below does not seem to work

```
$theFiles = Array("1.wav","2.wav","output.wav");
exec("java -jar WaveAppender.jar $theFiles");
```

I do not get any errors but the out.wav is not written.

Am I calling exec() wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use arrays directly like that in a string.  The resulting command line that would generated would be:

```
java -jar WaveAppender.jar Array
```

If what you actually want is

```
java -jar WaveAppender.jar 1.wav 2.wav 3.wav
```

then you need to do this:

```
exec("java -jar WaveAppender.jar " . implode (' ', $theFiles));
```

Comment: If you want to properly pass arguments into Java's `argv`, you'll want to implode with a space, not a comma.

Comment: I am getting an error with that code.Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp\www\drum\index.php on line 4.Line is the exec() code you gave me above.

Comment: Here is the complete code.$theFiles = Array("bass.wav","hihat.wav","output.wav");
exec("java -jar WaveAppender.jar ". implode(',' $theFiles));

Comment: Use `implode(',', $theFiles)`.

Comment: @Zach Rattner: Updated answer to fix that.

Comment: It gives no error now.But the out.wav is not written to the directory.I try with command line and it works,just not with exec()?

Answer (score 3):

There are several things to keep in mind here:

1. Many hosting providers consider `exec` to be a dangerous function call. For this reason, it may not be available on your server. For more information on checking whether `exec` is enabled on your system, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938120/check-if-exec-is-disabled).
2. Your files are stored in an array. Given the code you posted, you are actually passing this string to `exec`:

   `java -jar WaveAppender.jar Array`

   To fix this, try using `implode` to concatenate all elements of the array into a string, like so:

   `exec('java -jar WaveAppender.jar ' . implode(' ', $theFiles));`

   For more information on `implode`, see [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).
3. Remember that `exec` returns a value, and you can also pass in an array to be filled with all the output of the program. This would be useful for handling errors in your web app. For more information on `exec`, see [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Comment: This is on localhost so it is not a problem with exec().Thanks for the help.

Comment: Tried the function mentioned and it reported 1.So I guess exec() is enabled.