# How to communicate a Java server using PHP?

Tags: java, php, tcp

I succeeded setup a Java TCP server.
I succeeded setup a PHP TCP client. (By using `stream_get_contents`, `fwrite`)
The problem is, when I try to transfer my PHP TCP client to a hosting company (in my case GoDaddy.com), it doesn't work. GoDaddy probably blocks stream_get_contents.
What are my alternatives?

Comment: See this question to check if it is really disabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938120/check-if-exec-is-disabled

Comment: by JAVA tcp server, you mean something like JBoss or Tomcat?

Comment: java.net.ServerSocket

Comment: So you mean using sockets to communicate in TCP/IP.

Comment: Where does your server run? How do you connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try your code locally? if it works locally maybe you should try these:
-fix firewall issue on JAVA tcp server machine
-check for NAT/PAT configuration
and if it still doesn't work,
I don't think you can communicate with other servers at socket level on hosting environments(not sure). but why don't you use web services?

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: @Mike I don't think so