# PHP shell_exec will not run ls

Tags: php, exec

I am running the following php script:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

echo nl2br("Before\n\n");

$out = shell_exec("ls -lart");
echo "<pre>$out</pre>";

echo nl2br("After\n\n");


?>
```

I cannot get `shell_exec` or `exec` to work at all. The script above produces:

```
Before
After
```

but nothing in between.

Comment: Is ls on the $PATH? Does the uid have a shell? Is php running chroot?

Comment: What does "uid have a shell" mean? And what is chroot. Could you explain further please

Comment: Here hou have (robust) function
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12980534/3896852

Answer (score 0):

I think `shell_exec` function is disabled in your php.ini . You can check it by

```
if(function_exists('shell_exec')) {
    echo "shell_exec is enabled";
} else {
    echo "shell_exec is disabled";
}
```

Open your php.ini and navigate to section `disable_functions`

If shell_exec is listed under there , remove it.

Then restart apache / php handler.

Also If Safe Mode is enabled this function will not be available. You need to disable it.