# Dreamhost site doesnot support fopen functionality

Tags: php, wordpress

Actually i want to send zip file to the dropbox .But when i try to open my file using fopen then this issue comes.
**fopen(www.cloud01.wptemplate.net_09_10_2015_16_1444437876.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cle1296/cloud01.wptemplate.net/wp-content/plugins/wp-cloud-safe/includes/UltimateBackup.php on line 830.**
My server is dreamhost.I execute the same code on another server and don't face any issue.It seems that dreamhost disabled the fopen function.So kindly give me an alternative way

```
 function sendToDropbox() {

    try {

        $this->log('Sending file to DropBox');
       $dbxClient = new dbx\Client($this->dropboxGeneratedAccessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");


        $f = fopen($this->backupFilename, "r+");


        $dbxClient->uploadFile($this->dropboxUploadPath . $this->backupFilename, dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);

    } catch (Exception $e) {



        $this->log('ERROR while uploading file to DropBox');

    }

}
```

Comment: I use DreamHost as well and I can assure you that there is no such thing as *"my webhost must have disabled the function X because I've got an error"*. Look to your error message again.

Comment: As Alan stated, function is indeed working. Problem is that file is not there.

Comment: i tried a lot but got struck on that issue.If this not a DreamHost problem then why my script is working well on another server..i will be thankful to you for your help

Comment: @viktor77.I assure you file exists. :)

Comment: Do this, then: implement the function described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938120/check-if-exec-is-disabled) and deploy it at your webhost (change 'exec' to 'fopen'), then execute it. If it returns you `true`, it's enabled. If `false`, disabled (beware that `ini_get()` can be also disabled to prevent internal config sniffing).

Comment: i check it.it return true.But will you please tell me why this is working fine on another servers.What will be the issue.Thanx for helping.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the file obviously is not correct, either because the file does not exist or simply what you passed to `fopen()` is not the actual location of the backup. Use the full path to the file to be absolutely sure, for example if your backup is at:

`/home/cle1296/cloud01.wptemplate.net/my_backups/backup.zip`

...then make sure to pass it to your `fopen()` and you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: Now i change the file path as you said. But it is again giving me the same error.Here is my code. $f = fopen("/home/cle1296/cloud01.wptemplate.net/wp-content/plugins/wp-cloud-safe/lib/testing.zip", "r+");

Comment: if you're 100% sure that the path is valid 100%, then maybe backup file's permissions are too strict. use FTP or SSH to change it's permissions to 755 and check again...