# Simple whois lookup script doesnt work when i use exec command

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel for my whois domain search. But when i use exec command in my controller, there is no output

My controller

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use App\Models\User;
    
    
    class SorgulaController extends Controller
    {
        //
       
    
         //
         function sorgula (Request $req)
         {   
        $domain = $req->get('domain');
       
    
        return view('results', compact( 'domain' , ));
    
    
             
         }
    }
    
    ?>
```

My form blade

```
<form action="/tr/sonuc" method="post">,
            @csrf
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input  type="text" name="domain" 
                                    class="form-control form-control-lg" value=""
                                    placeholder="" required>
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                
                                <br>
                               
                                
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark d-grid gap-2 col-3 mx-auto">Sorgula</button>
    
                                <br>
                                <p class="text-center"> <a class="text-primary" href="https://domaintelekom.com/login">oturum açın.</a></p>

                            </form>
```

My result blade

```
    <?php 
exec("whois $domain" , $data);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);

echo "</pre>";
?>
```

My route

```
       Route::get('/tr', function () {     
        return view('index');
    });
    
    Route::get('/tr/sonuc', function () {     
        return view('results');
    });
Route::post('/tr/sonuc',    [App\Http\Controllers\SorgulaController::class, 'sorgula']);
```

This is the result i got

[image: This is the result i go]

When i use vanilla php there are domain records. But there is no record when i use Laravel.
Why is that?

Comment: Please check this article: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php. I think that your syntax is incorrect. I mean this part: exec("whois $domain" , $data);

Comment: But it works in vanilla php.

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/k4rJ_ED8fgBFJdj0TYJMsw

Comment: https://bobcares.com/blog/how-to-enable-exec-function-in-php-ini/

Comment: i checked phpinfo() there is no disabled function. https://prnt.sc/fTG3VlqLbHn4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer the reason why my shell_exec or exec command doesnt work, it beacuse in my Centos panel there is no 43 port number. When i open port 43 it worked. Just add port number 43 and restart the firewall, it will work after that. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful when using process on laravel

```js
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
    
...

$current = new Process('whois google.com');
$current->run();

if (!$current->isSuccessful()) {
  // throw new ProcessFailedException($current);
}
$current = $current->getOutput();
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/Kx3F41sBJmXg i got this error when i use that

Comment: write using array

Process(['whois', 'google.com'])

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: It is works but now page is blank. There is no records

Comment: can you show me the contents of dd($current)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/NqTpeItE9gqT it is empty

Comment: I can run it
https://prnt.sc/992AMHvkcWMm

Comment: I am working on live site not local. Maybe because of that i don't know why.

Comment: maybe your server has disabled the function to run the exec function, or you are using a hosting that is not allowed to use it, check phpinfo

or see to enable https://openjournaltheme.com/how-to-enable-and-disable-exec-php-function-in-ojs-omp-ops

Comment: I checked phpinfo, I said in the comment above. https://prnt.sc/fTG3VlqLbHn4 there is no disabled function

Comment: try to check if exec disable using

if( false !== strpos(ini_get("disable_functions"), "exec") ) {
 // exec() is disabled

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938120/check-if-exec-is-disabled

Comment: i checked your code but there is no record again. echo (int)function_exists('exec'); when i use this code i got  1 as a output. I guess that means exec function is available.

Comment: I think the code is fine, I can run it on my local. maybe you just need to change the server environment according to your local environment. or try contacting your hosting provider

Comment: another solution is to use the whois API