# Run python script from php on webserver

Tags: php, python, webserver

I have a free webspace hosted by altervista where i have one script python and one script php. What i want to do is call the python script using the php script. I googled for a solution and i found several questions about it, i tried different proposed solutions but no one worked for me.

Here the php script code:

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

and here the python script code:

```
print("Hello")
```

When i run the php script nothing happens.
What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried "python test.py" instead? Also, does your host even support python scripts to be called?

Comment: i already tried it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hosting company might have disabled the shell-exec function for security reasons. I'm not saying it is the case, but you should check that first before even trying to run shell_exec.

Seealso:
[PHP - How to know if server allows shell_exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581560/php-how-to-know-if-server-allows-shell-exec)

[Plus, back in 2012, it wasn't possible with Altervista...](http://forum.it.altervista.org/i-servizi-di-altervista/166338-comandi-shell_exec.html)