# making shell zip accessible to php

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

Hi got a LEMP stack un Ubuntu 18.04 with php 7.2.5
server info says 
Shell Exec  Is Supported
Shell Exec Zip  Not Supported

therefore some of my plugins says
This server is not configured for the Shell Zip engine - please use a different engine mode. To make 'Shell Zip' available, ask your host to:
1. Install the zip executable and make it accessible to PHP.

I have tries this code
[PHP - How to know if server allows shell_exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581560/php-how-to-know-if-server-allows-shell-exec)

```
  if(function_exists('shell_exec')) {
        echo "exec is enabled";
    }
```

and the function is enabled

however when i test if it is executable with the code below nothing happens.

> As DanFromGermany pointed out, you probably check then if it is
>   executable. Something like this would do it

```
if(shell_exec('echo foobar') == 'foobar'){
    echo 'shell_exec works';
}
```

or tried this, returns nothing as well just white page

```
 // Exec function exists.
    // Exec is not disabled.
    // Safe Mode is not on.
    $exec_enabled =
       function_exists('exec') &&
       !in_array('exec', array_map('trim', explode(', ', ini_get('disable_functions')))) &&
       strtolower(ini_get('safe_mode')) != 1
    ;


    if($exec_enabled) { exec('blah'); }
```

I have also checked with the code below from https://wpguru.co.uk/2014/01/how-to-test-if-a-shell-command-will-work-in-php/  and it does work

```
// helper function
function checkShellCommand($command) {
    $returnValue = shell_exec("$command");
    if(empty($returnValue)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

// test the shell command you'd like to use
if (!checkShellCommand('uname -a')) {
    print 'This command cannot be executed.';
} else {
    echo shell_exec('uname -a');
}
```

So, could anyone tell me how can I **make it accessible to PHP**

Many thanks

Comment: "therefore some of my plugins says" - where's the code checking this? "Shell Exec Zip Not Supported" sounds pretty strange to me

Answer (score 0):

this was solved by

```
apt-get install zip unzip
```