# PHP copy file from server using linux

Tags: php, linux

```
$GET=shell_exec(`/usr/local/bin/ncftpget -R -v -u XXXXX -p XXXXX XX.XX.XX.21 $DESTDIR /CustomsPollerPDF/processed/$pdf_filename`);
```

im using 
php to copy file from one server location to another. and i want to log the result/error in $GET variable but im unable to get it. it variable return empty.

Comment: Maybe, it's because the linux copy command doesn't return nothing...

Comment: Also check if it shell_exec is even enabled on your server, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21581873/1526963

Comment: Also the **backticks** already execute the command. Thus leaving `shell_exec()` with the output of said command, if any. Which very likely will not do anything meaningful.

Comment: shell_exec is enabled on my server. is there anyway i can get error result to the variable