# How to run PHP file from AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bash

I need to run a PHP file from my AJAX Jquery.. Here is my try...

My Button as below

```html
<input type="button"
       style="background-color:#00BFFF;padding:3px;border: none;"
       id="btnnew2"
       class="button"
       name="pc73"
       value="Get The Latest"
/>
```

My Jquery as below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.button').click(function(){

        if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        else{
            //$('#loading').show();
            $.ajax({
                url : 'testrun.php',
                type : 'POST',
                success : function (result) {
                    alert("done");
                },
                error : function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

To have a better understanding I will attach `testrun.php` as below,

```php
<?php        

    $old_path = getcwd();
    chdir('/home/scripts/');
    $output = shell_exec("./testscript.sh");
    chdir($old_path);
    echo $output;

?>
```

and finally my testscript.sh as follows,

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/scripts/
export PATH="/root/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"
export TEMP=/home/svradmin/tmp
    
python3 testupdate.py
```

When I click the button I am getting an alert as `done` but my `testupdate.py` has not executed.. my testupdate.py as follows, from that I could identify whether the python script has run or not.

```py
import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import statistics as st
import mysql.connector as sql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"]="3"
    
sql_transfer_Query = "insert into  updatetest(text) values ('executed');"
print(sql_transfer_Query)
    
#Write to Final Alarm Table
db_connection_write = sql.connect(host='localhost', database='test', user='XXXX', password='XXX',charset='utf8')
cursor = db_connection_write.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_transfer_Query)
db_connection_write.commit()
    
if (db_connection_write.is_connected()):
    cursor.close()
    db_connection_write.close()
    print("MySQL connection is closed")
            
##exit()
```

I know this is too long process... But I need to stick on it due to some other requirement... Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Note:  without button clicking, If I use `bash testscript.sh` to run the  script. I could see my python file has run without any issue.. Hope this is clear..

Comment: What output do you get if you call `testrun.php` directly from the browser?

Comment: The command is `bash testscript.sh` not just `./testscript.sh`?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware when I directly run **php testrun.php** also I could see my python script has excecuted.. But this is not executing when I use ajax...

Comment: Have you checked that shell_exec is not disabled for that particular vhost? This would probably allow it to be run on cli but then fail when run from AJAX.

Comment: @kissumisha No I didn't check.. Kindly help me to check this...

Comment: @KIKOSoftware No I use **bash testscript.sh** to run directly... As mentioned previously both  **bash testscript.sh** and **php testrun.php** works.. only issue with AJAX..

Comment: `/root/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin`: I think, I HOPE, that your webserver user doesn't have access to `/root`. If all python dependencies are there then I would expect `python3 testupdate.py` to errput something like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

Comment: @Fravadona does changing the root permission to 755 will resolve this issue?

Comment: @Codec737 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581560/php-how-to-know-if-server-allows-shell-exec

Comment: @Fravadona Same issue. I made whole path to 755 but still I could not run.. my php website is at var/www/html/project folder.. testrun.php also in same folder.. But when I directly run that php, my python is running. is there can be a permission issue then?

Comment: You should take a look at your http error logs; the issues should be reported there

Comment: FYI: `e.preventDefault();` - you have no `e` there. You need `$('.button').click(function(e){` to _receive_ the event object that gets passed to the callback function, so that it will be available under that name inside the function.