# What is the documented behavior of functions invocation listed in disable_functions

Tags: php

I were not able to find a proper source stating what the intended behaviour is when invoking a function listed in `disable_functions`.

My *observation* is that a log entry is created saying something like

> [04-Sep-2014 16:17:55 UTC] PHP Warning: curl_exec() has been disabled
>   for security reasons in {file} {line}

But what does the function return in such a case? And I mean what is it *documented* to return?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP exec - check if enabled or disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749591/php-exec-check-if-enabled-or-disabled)

Comment: Be sure to take note of the comment on the accepted answer. That should answer your question

Comment: @Machavity in what regard is this a duplicate of #2749591?!

Comment: @DCoder: perfect, thanks. That would be my accepted answer. How would I handle that? Can you transform your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not formally documented, but if you look at [the source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/898e1570a2f1051d40045545e3bd3640247799fa/Zend/zend_API.c#L2777), PHP has a placeholder function that gets called instead of a disabled function. This placeholder function only generates the warning and does not explicitly return any value. This "lack of a return value" is translated to a `NULL` before your PHP code sees it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen it documented, but it returns `NULL`.  With `disable_functions = file_get_contents`:

```
var_dump(file_get_contents(__FILE__));
```

> Warning: file_get_contents() has been disabled for security reasons in test.php on line 2
>
> NULL

Same results with `curl_exec`.