# How to mute error logging of a disabled function despite an at operator @?

Tags: php, error-handling, error-reporting, error-log, ini-set

Does anybody know how to make a disabled function (in my case `ini_set()`) stop throwing an error? I usually have it like `@ini_set()` but on this WP plugin, it STILL fills the error_log with:

> [30-Apr-2018 12:01:39 UTC] All-in-One Event Calendar: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons @ /home/burp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar/all-in-one-event-calendar.php:81 #2

I suspect it's because that ini_set actually sets a callback function and another ini_set() is called within that ini_set() function defined.  Here's the error_log'ed line 81 in question:

```
@ini_set( 'unserialize_callback_func', 'spl_autoload_call' );
```

I'm the server administrator and I disabled ini_set() years ago and I have no problem with this, I just want to MUTE the error logging on that script. +100 WP sites that all include ini_set() are NOT reporting any error, only this particular one, despite the @ before the ini_set().

Comment: Did you read the error message? It's the not function throwing that error, it's PHP throwing that error.

Comment: I know? I'm asking how to MUTE the ini_set()

Comment: The best way to disable the error would be to remove/fix the line in question. If this is a 3rd party script, contact the maintainers to find out if it's necessary and if you can remove it.

Comment: Jesus christ, I KNOW, I'm the server administrator and I disabled ini_set() years ago and I have no problem with this, I just want to MUTE the error logging on that script.  +100 WP sites that all include ini_set() are NOT reporting any error, only this particular one, despite the @ before the ini_set().  Is this clearer?

Comment: @that-ben learn to use your title/body to clarify the question clearly instead of adding words to make it seem comical in the future. The confusion has arose because you never clarified exactly what you meant.

Comment: The `@` decorator just suppresses the *default error **display** handler*, not any custom ones or logging per se. (It's often called "error suppression operator", but that's somewhat misleading.)

Comment: @mario At last an answer that's related to the question! Thanks for some light at the end of the tunnel Mario! Any suggestion how to overcome it? (mute the error_logging)

Comment: For portable code (under your circumstances), the program could check whether or not `ini_set` is disabled. If you need to support EOL PHP versions, you can parse ini_get returns (if you didn't disable that as well): [PHP exec - check if enabled or disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2749591/367456) - Or make use of the parameter of [`get_defined_functions`](https://php.net/function.get-defined-functions.php)

Comment: @hakre I do not need to know if ini_set() is disabled, it's always disabled on all sites on this server and I want to leave it like that for security purposes.  I only want to mute that particular line which is the only ini_set() line to trigger this error log on +100 WP sites that all have at least 1 ini_set that's perfectly muted with @ini_set(), this is the only one that sticks to error logging for some reason, probably because it's a callback which could in turn include another ini_set() that's not muted.  I have to download all the files and mass search on all files.

Comment: @that-ben: I've read that. Either fix the error handler and/or make the code portable (for which I just commented, for the other others have commented). If you knew ini_set is disabled you could not use it under that circumstance. But I got it: Just fix the damn error_handler you've got a problem with. Do that now :)

Comment: So many ways that things went wrong in this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) `@` would normally suppress the error message, however a custom error handler defined with [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) can still cause the error to be logged via [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).

[`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) will return 0 if the call that triggered the error was preceded by an `@`. The error handling function should check that before logging the error:

```
if (error_reporting()) {
    // Report the error
    error_log(...)
}
```

Looking at the calendar code below, you can see that [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) is called for non-fatal errors. You could simply add a check for [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) in that script.

https://github.com/wp-plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar/blob/86c4e20dab7b199b20207fb3918a8807f7342fab/lib/exception/handler.php#L287

Alternatively you could disable [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) or re-enable [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) for that page.

**POST MORTEM EDIT:** It is worth noting that despite the error log specifying the error was caused by ini_set() being disabled, the error was originating from deeper in the callback of the function defined within the ini_set() in question (the line 81 displayed in OP).  So basically, the error is not even relevant at all.  It's bubbling up to the ini_set() and creates confusion as the reason and even the line is not about the error that was actually thrown.

Comment: So error_reporting(0); then that faulty line then error_reporting(E_ALL); ?

Comment: But doesn't @ effectively do this (setting the error reporting level to 0 temporarily) already? So it would only need to check that error handler, correct?

Comment: To honor the `@` operator, the user-defined error handler function needs to manually check `if (error_reporting())` before calling `error_log`, which it doesn't seem to do now. See the snippets above.